# Statement expected, found Py:ELIF_KEYWORD

Tags: python, syntax-error

I am also getting error Statement expected, found Py:COLON"

What is going wrong? This is a text based adventure game project I am working on to practice `elif` and `else` statements. Below is my code.

```
def start():
    print("You wake up on the floor. Sweating. Your head is pounding, you find that you are "
          "sitting in a dark, cold, eerily quiet room...")
    print("You hear water dripping, the quality of this place makes you think of an old basement.")
    print("Except, there are no haphazardly placed boxes labeled with things like "
          "'Christmas Decorations' or 'Old Photos'...")
    print("You have that deep, aching and alarming feeling in your "
          "stomach that can only be described as exactly what it is..." 
          "fear. You rise to your feet and take in the sheer darkness "
          "that has seemingly swallowed you up. Desperately" 
          "you reach for your pockets and find to your surprise that "
          "you have a lighter! Upon lighting it, you find that" 
          "there is a note taped to the wall, between two doors. "
          "It reads 'Welcome to hell!' There are two doors in front")
    print("of you. The one on the left leads to safety but unhappiness. "
          "The door on the right leads to choas but "
          "eternal happiness. Choose wisely.")

    answer = input(">").lower()

    if "l" in answer:
        spider_isles()
    elif "r" in answer:
        fire_coaster()
    else:
        game_over("By choosing not to choose you've chosen death on repeat! You will die in your dreams in horrific"
                  "and in realistic detail every night. Didn't you read the fine print?")


def game_over(reason):
    print("\n" + reason )
    print("Game over, sucka!")
    play_again()

def safe_haven():
    print("Welcome to the safe haven! You are now in a room filled with amenities and SAFETY!"
          "You have a nice cozy warm bed to sleep in until you must face the "
          "terrors of tomorrow! OR you can choose the door on the end of the room. It is"
          "entirely unknown. "
          "1.) Choose the door to the unknown."
          "2.) Choose to remain in your current arrangement.")
    answer = input(">")
    if answer == "1":
        print("You've beat the game and you've escaped the purgatory!")
    if answer == '2':
        print("You've chosen to keep your current arrangements. On your first day your new allies turned"
                  "on you due to being jealous of your safe haven! You are dead.")
    game_over("YOU ARE DEAD!")


def spider_isles():
        print("/nI reach for the knob on the left, as I turn the knob and open the dark red door I find that"
              "I am overwhelmed by the enormity of the space before me. But most of all, I literally"
              "cannot process the amount of spiders in front of me. There is one spider in particular"
              "that varies from 3-10 times larger than the rest. Definitely the Trump of spiders."
              "He is staring at me, almost in a calculated way. I can't breathe. I thought"
              "I must be dead when the spider asked me 'Will you choose..."
              "1.) to join us, live among us and be protected for the rest of your life or;"
              "2.) be eaten alive by us here and now?")
        answer = input(">.")
        reason = "Wrong choice!"
        if answer == '1':
            print("Trump spider scurried disgustingly out of your way revealing a slowly clearing path"
              "for you to follow, it looks like it leads to another building with a door, you "
              "walk the spider lined black moving mass of a path to the building and head "
              "to the door, you don't hesitate to"
              "open it, anywhere must be better... right?")
        safe_haven()
        elif answer == '2'
        print("Guess it's game over for you! Took the easy way out, eh?")
        game_over(reason)
        else:
        print("Not choosing doesn't help you escape. The spiders still ate you alive, pal!")
        game_over(reason)

def fire_coaster():
    print("Hesitantly, I reach for the know on my right. I think to myself,"
          "uncertainty is worth it if it means eternal happiness right? "
          "As I pull open the know to the electric blue door, I am consumed by the screams."
          "I hear mechanical noises, too. The screams are what shocked me the most, the "
          "mechanical noise was unmistakable, roller coasters. But... the screams...."
          "They weren't the screams of excited theme park goers. These screams were "
          "blood curdling. I was greeted by a man who clearly, uh... worked here."
          "It was then I noticed his creepy dead stare and smirk. His shirt was covered in blood"
          "and he was patiently waiting and lightly swaying to the music from the carousel."
          "He suddenly stopped and tilted his head slowly toward the other shoulder and "
          "asked, so..."
          "1.) Do you want to stay and play? Everyday that you survive the terror you win a "
          "safe night and 10 grand."
          "2.) You get a chance to run, but I will catch you and I will eat your eyes out.")
    answer= input(">.")
    if answer == '1':
        print("You've chosen to stay and play!")
safe_haven()

elif if answer == '2':
    reason= "You really thought running would work?"
    print("You've chosen to run! Not very smart! You made it to the fun house! You encounter the evil carnie"
        "in a room  of mirrors! You watched yourself get stabbed in every angle imaginable!")
game_over(reason)

else:
print("Not choosing IS choosing. You made it to the fun house! You encounter the evil carnie"
      "in a room of mirrors! You watched yourself get stabbed in every angle imaginable! ")
game_over(reason)



def play_again():
    print("\nDo you want to play again? (y or n)")
    answer = input(">").lower()
    if "y" in answer:
        start()
    else:
        exit()

        start()
```

Comment: There is an `elif` followed by an `if` in `elif if answer == '2':`.

Comment: That's also a syntax error, but the one that triggers an unexpected Py:ELIF_KEYWORD is further up; an if block is terminated by missing indentation, and then followed by an elif.

Comment: I can not believe I didn't notice that. I was so flustered that I was looking at everything except my incorrect usage of elif! Thank you!

Answer (score 1):

This part is not correctly indented:

```
    if answer == '1':
        print("Trump spider scurried disgustingly out of your way revealing a slowly clearing path"
          "for you to follow, it looks like it leads to another building with a door, you "
          "walk the spider lined black moving mass of a path to the building and head "
          "to the door, you don't hesitate to"
          "open it, anywhere must be better... right?")
    safe_haven()
    elif answer == '2'
    print("Guess it's game over for you! Took the easy way out, eh?")
    game_over(reason)
    else:
    print("Not choosing doesn't help you escape. The spiders still ate you alive, pal!")
    game_over(reason)
```